# How to sort key by order of last y-values?

Tags: gnuplot, visualization

I already managed a graph in gnuplot. Now i want to optimize the order in the key. My solution would be to do it outside of gnuplot in form of preprocessing the data. But maybe someone of you knows an easy solution in gnuplot?

Position of entries in key should be sorted by last y values. This would result in non crossing lines from each entry to the curves.

Temperatures via gnuplot:

[image]

data is in form of:

```
2023-10-28 14:17:01     59.125  34.875  43.500  25.375  26.125  45.312  44.687  26.125  57.750
2023-10-28 14:18:01     59.125  34.937  43.875  25.375  26.125  45.437  44.750  26.187  57.750
2023-10-28 14:19:01     59.250  35.000  43.937  25.375  26.125  45.437  44.812  26.187  57.875
2023-10-28 14:20:01     59.187  35.062  43.562  25.375  26.125  45.562  44.812  26.250  57.750
2023-10-28 14:21:01     59.125  35.125  43.625  25.375  26.125  45.562  44.875  26.312  57.812
```

the interesting parts of my gnuplot script

```
stats 'temp.txt' using (last1=$1,last2=$2,last3=$3,last4=$4,last5=$5,last6=$6,last7=$7,last8=$8,last9=$9,last10=$10) nooutput
set size 0.8,1
set arrow from graph 1,first last4  to screen 0.8, first 70 nohead
set key outside Left reverse

plot \
  "temp.txt"         using  1:4 with lines title sprintf("Vorlauf Solar, %0.1f°"  , last4 ) at screen 0.84, first 70,   \
  "temp.txt"         using  1:3 with lines title sprintf("Warmwasser, %0.1f°"     , last3 ) at screen 0.84, first 65,   \
```

Comment: Question answered? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is basically a duplicate of [Reordering gnuplot key entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290504/7295599), I voted for reopening this question in order to give an answer for gnuplot>=5.4.0, which is simpler than the answer(s) there. Furthermore, the user of that question doesn't seem to be active anymore.

Comments:

- do `stats` to get the number of rows and columns
- plot the order number (=column number-1) and the last y-value into a datablock `$Temp`, and at the same time merge all columnheaders into the string `headers`
- plot `$Temp` into the datablock `$Order` using `smooth zsort` (requires gnuplot>=5.4.0). This is probably the easiest way (so far) to sort values with *gnuplot-only*. The rows will contain the last y-values in column 1 (descending order) and the corresponding order number (in column 2).
- plot your data and the key entries in corresponding order

**Data:** `SO77379457.dat`

```
X Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5 Data6 Data7 Data8
0  96.4  93.3  99.5  97.3  95.9  91.9  98.9  98.0
1  96.1  93.2  99.5  97.6  96.0  91.9  98.7  98.4
2  96.0  93.1  99.3  97.7  95.7  91.5  99.2  98.2
3  96.5  92.8  99.2  97.8  96.1  92.0  99.2  98.3
4  96.7  92.3  99.0  97.4  95.7  91.8  99.0  97.9
5  96.3  92.3  99.4  97.5  95.7  92.3  98.7  98.2
6  95.9  92.7  99.4  97.4  96.0  91.9  99.1  98.7
7  95.8  92.4  99.2  97.0  96.4  91.6  99.5  98.5
```

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.4.0)

```
### re-order key in order of last y-value
reset session

FILE = "SO77379457.dat"

stats FILE u 0 nooutput
rowMax = STATS_records-1
colMax = STATS_columns

headers = ''
set table $Temp
    plot for [col=2:colMax] FILE every rowMax u ($0==0?headers=headers.' '.columnheader(col):col-1):col w table
set table $Order
    plot $Temp u 2:1:(-$2) smooth zsort
unset table

set key noautotitle out Left reverse

plot for [col=2:*] FILE u 1:col w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc col-1, \
     for [i=0:rowMax-1] $Order every ::i::i u (NaN):(NaN):(t=int($2)) w lp pt 7 lc var ti word(headers,t)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]